# Как получить статус код?

Tags: angular2

Использую `HttpRequest` и хочу при каких-либо ошибках получить статус код.

Нашел вот такое решение:

```
http
  .post<T>('/yoururl', {observe: 'response'})
  .subscribe(resp => {
     console.log(resp);
  });
```

но у HttpRequest нету параметра `observe`.

Если просматривать объект ошибки, то там так же нет ничего интересно "Бла бла бла неизвестная ошибка".

Как мне получить статус код?

Comment: второй параметр `post` это бади, а не опции

Comment: @overthesanity, ой... не заметил... А этот параметр никак не повлияет на возвращаемые данные от сервера? Например, я шлю постом и ожидаю какого-то ответа от сервера в виде JSON'а.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response